# I want my code to execute after every seconds and plot the data which will be changing after every n seconds

Tags: python-3.6

This is the code which I am using but the problem with it is I have to close the old plot so as for the code to generate a new plot after every n second. What I want is it automatically generate the new plot closing the old plot once the code executes.

```
     import time
     from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     starttime=time.time()
     while True:
     #code which reads data from an excel sheet which changes fter every n 
      seconds
     #code to rewrite the data structuring it in a new csv file
     #code to plot the data from csv file
     time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

Comment: You can use timer object. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: Do we have threading class in python-3.6? I mean it is showing error whenever I am trying to install timer or threading via pip. Actually, I am new to python so I don't have enough idea.

Comment: You don't have to install timer or threading. It is a built-in module. Just import using `from threading import Timer`

Comment: It says it cannot import name 'Timer'

Comment: It should work. Just type `from threading import Timer` in python console and check. If you get an error post it here.